# Can't return typeahead values from meteor server method back to client

Tags: meteor, typeahead.js, typeahead

trying to implement Sergey-t's Typeahead package on a form in my meteor app.

The issue is, I can't seem to return the typeahead results from the server back to the client.

Typeahead works if I make a test array on the client side and return it via the helper.

Also, all the query results are logging successfully in the server console. The only issue is I cant seem to get them back to the client.

My JS client console is not showing any errors, which seems strange.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<template name="typeaheadTemplate">

<!-- <input id="entry-field" class="typeahead input-lg form-control" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Paste or Enter your ID" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off" data-source="search"/> -->

<input class="form-control typeahead" name="textEntry" type="text"
placeholder="Paste or Enter your ID ..."
autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off"
data-source="search"/>

</template>
```

JS Client-Side Code

```
Template.typeaheadTemplate.rendered = function() {
    Meteor.typeahead.inject();
};

Template.typeaheadTemplate.helpers({

    search: function(query, sync, callback) {
      // alert( "typeaheadTemplate.search() " ) ;
      // debugger;
      Meteor.call('search', query, {}, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return err;
        }
        callback(res.map(function(v){ return {value: v.Name}; }));
      });
    }

  });
```

JS Server-Side Code

```
typeahead = new Mongo.Collection("typeahead");
typeahead._ensureIndex({"Name": "text"});         // index by Name

Meteor.methods({

    search: function(query, options) {
      // console.log("Search Result") ;
      // return "SEARCH RESULT" ;
    // debugger;
    // if (!query) return [];

    options = options || {};
    // guard against client-side Denial of Service: hard limit to 50
    if (options.limit) { options.limit = Math.min(50, Math.abs(options.limit)); }
    else { options.limit = 50; }

    var re = "^" + query + ".*$" ;
    var th = typeahead.find({ "Name" : {$regex : re } }, {fields: { Name : 1 }});
    console.log("query " + query + " -> " + th.count() );
    th.forEach(function (autoCompleteString) {
      console.log("> " + autoCompleteString.Name);
    });
    return th;
  }});
```

If it helps, here are the packages I'm using:

```
accounts-password          1.1.4  Password support for accounts
accounts-ui                1.1.6  Simple templates to add login widgets to an app
anonyfox:scrape            0.0.10  Scrape any Website or RSS/Atom-Feed with ease
blaze-html-templates       1.0.1  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI with Meteor B...
check                      1.1.0  Check whether a value matches a pattern
ecmascript                 0.1.6* Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files
ejson                      1.0.7  Extended and Extensible JSON library
es5-shim                   4.1.14  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
fortawesome:fontawesome    4.5.0  Font Awesome (official): 500+ scalable vector icons, ...
froatsnook:request         2.67.0  A Simplified HTTP client which supports retrieving b...
http                       1.1.1  Make HTTP calls to remote servers
insecure                   1.0.4  (For prototyping only) Allow all database writes from...
jquery                     1.11.4  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
less                       2.5.1  Leaner CSS language
meteorhacks:npm            1.5.0  Use npm modules with your Meteor App
mobile-experience          1.0.1  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                      1.1.3  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
mrt:cheerio                0.3.2  Simple Cheerio NPM wrapper
mrt:fittext                1.2.0  FitText packaged for Meteor.
mrt:jquery-easing          1.3.0  GSGD's jQuery easing plugin for Meteor
mrt:twit                   0.2.0  Twitter API Client
npm-container              1.2.0+ Contains all your npm dependencies
okgrow:promise             0.9.5  Utilities for Promise-based wrappers, method calls, h...
peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal  1.0.4  Simple usage of bootstrap 3 modals.
sacha:spin                 2.3.1  Simple spinner package for Meteor
sergeyt:typeahead          0.11.1_8  Autocomplete package for meteor powered by twitter...
session                    1.1.1  Session variable
standard-app-packages      1.0.6  Moved to meteor-platform
standard-minifiers         1.0.2  Standard minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
stevezhu:fbgraph           2.0.0  Node.js module to access the Facebook graph api.
timmyg:wow                 1.0.1  WOW css animations
tracker                    1.0.9  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
twbs:bootstrap             3.3.6  The most popular front-end framework for developing r...
underscore                 1.0.4  Collection of small helpers: _.map, _.each, ...
```

Comment: instead of returning data by method, try to `subscribe` these search result.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed thanks for the suggestion. I don't understand how this would fix the issue. The official documentation for meteor typeahead has no suggestion for publish/subscribe, and suggests to only use meteor.call for all serverside typeahead.

Comment: if you please take a close look at the examples, you'd find something `dbName.find()` in the client side which basically means there are some data subscribed.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I've closely examined the documents for any mention of subscribe or publish. Take a look at the main page here https://github.com/sergeyt/meteor-typeahead  there is zero mention of Pub/Sub, also the only server side example on that page is a meteor.call.  There is also no mention of any subscribe or publish on the docs page: https://github.com/sergeyt/meteor-typeahead/blob/master/docs.md

Comment: Also to mention, I have the query results printing in the server console, I just cannot return them to the client. Outside of Sergey-T's examples, there is next to zero examples of large, working typeahead server-side implementations for Meteor anywhere on the internet.

Comment: That's what i was telling you about, method return doesn't store the information on `minimongo`. without `minimongo` storage, i don't know any way to look for db values.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Sure, but what I am saying is that what you are saying goes directly against *all* documentation currently available for how to use typeahead with Meteor. There is literally no document on how to use Meteor Typeahead with Publish/Subscribe. If you could point me in the direction of an example, that would be extremely helpful. A way you can return results that are happily displaying in the server console via a meteor.call, back to the client and into typeahead as a data-source.